Delphi Client connecting to HTTPS - TRestRequest.Execute a lot slower than TIdHttp.Post

server: Delphi VCL app, using TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge, TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL with SSLOptions.CertFile/KeyFile/OnGetPassword assigned. In WebModule, a WebActionItem.OnAction tied to /some/path returns a tiny amount of characters from the db. The whole OnAction handler takes cca 50 ms

client: Delphi (test) VCL app using TRestClient and TRestRequest (method=rmPost) accessing https://localhost:NNNN/some/path. First TRequest.Execute takes over 2000 ms, subsequent ones take cca 1100 ms to return the said tiny amount of characters.

client 2: Delphi (test) VCL app, using TIdHttp with IOHandler= instance of TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL. The execution of the request is a simple TIdHttp.Post(https://localhost:NNNN/some/path ..) - the first one takes slightly under 1000ms and subsequent ones cca 60 ms


Server runs interactively on localHost as do both clients. Both clients return the same correct result as expected. The server side timing does not change from one client to the next.
So my question is obviously - how can this be ? What could I be doing wrong in TRestRequest usage ? I'll provide more details if needed, but for starters I just want to get an idea whether Delphi TRestClient has any known problems ..
EDIT: Simply re-reading the question, I noticed the similarity in TIdHttp.Post first timing and TRestRequest.Execute subsequent timings. Could it be that TRestRequest re-creates SSL IOHandler for each call and loses all the caching benefits on performance?
EDIT2: TRESTRequest.Execute ends up in System.Net.HttpClient.Win.TWinHTTPClient.DoExecuteRequest() which spends all the time calling into winhttp.dll:WinHttpSendRequest(), so this is obviously an external problem (Windows Server 2019, WinHttp.dll version 10.0.17763.4492)..here the docs in case anyone has an idea what is slowing this down https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsendrequest
also this is worrying: https://microsoft.public.winhttp.narkive.com/x5OOQlt0/winhttp-15-second-delay-sending-my-data-caused-by-windowsupdate

You are likely not doing anything wrong. TRESTClient is just more complex than TIdHTTP. If you really want to know what's taking up the time, you will need to profile the RTL's source code.

Thanks Remy, that is reassuring!  Funny it will not be the first time I switch from TRestXXX to TIdXXX - I've done it already when writing Delphi clients for REST services cca 5 years ago. Problem then AFAIR was I could not access all the stuff I needed from HttpClient. It is very good feeling to know that Indy is working well, and that Borland is at fault  :) (because they've let Anders go)

Of course I should've known - this is not a Delphi problem, it is a MS Windows Http API being slow for whatever reason. The 15s slowdown problems linked above, seems to imply the WinHttpSendRequest() checks for Windows Updates on the same thread .. good timing to remind me why I  abhore MS ..

@RemyLebeau I'd be keen to hear what you think about my answer - it seems strange IPv6 would help - do you have any theories what is going on here ?

My bad. I assumed a problem on the client side - in fact the problem was on the server side !
In short: one needs to make sure to support both IPv4 and IPv6 when adding Port bindings to the TIdTCPServer or descendants.
In server, I had
    FServer: TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge;
...
       
    FServer.DefaultPort := NNNN

and
  FServer.Bindings.Add.Port := NNNN

This second clause (FServer.Bindings.Add), caused the TRESTRequest client slowdown, regardless of whether I used SSL (TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL ) or not. If I removed FServer.Bindings.Add, it all sped up. As I want to support responding on several different ports, I started playing around with all sort of variations and in the end this helped:
with  FServer.Bindings.Add do begin
  Port := NNNN; 
  IPVersion := Id_IPv6
end

Default is  IPVersion = Id_IPv4.
I do not have the rights to see the adapted settings, but have asked the Admin - he says this box has only IPv4 configured and has no IPv6 ?????
EDIT: However GStack.SupportsIPv6 check suggested by Remy return TRUE, so IPv6 is installed and obviously faster than IPv4.
In any case, after the change both TRESTRequest and TIdHttp on the client side work equally fast with or without SSL.
To try and be on the safe side I have now added code like this server-side:
with  FServer.Bindings.Add do begin
  Port := NNNN; 
  IPVersion := Id_IPv6
end;
with  FServer.Bindings.Add do begin
  Port := NNNN; 
  IPVersion := Id_IPv4
end

I am using Indy that comes with Delphi 11.3 - in IDCompilerDefines.inc:
...
{$DEFINE INDY100}
{$DEFINE 10_6_2}  //so developers can IFDEF for this specific version
...

So the slowdown described in the question above, could be a "feature" of WinHttp.dll client-side and Indy 10 server-side interaction under some very specific circumstances.
More info - WinHttp.dll slowdown only applies when using http(s)://localhost. If one uses http(s)://127.0.0.1, there is no slowdown, even if server Bindings contain only IPv4. Sort of makes sense if 127.0.0.1 forces the use of IPv4. Which could mean that localhost is somehow bound to IPv6, and WinHttp trying IPv6, failing and then switching to IPv4 is what causes slowdown when server Bindings do not include IPv6.
Albeit very old, I believe this could be related to the following question:
Firefox and Chrome slow on localhost; known fix doesn't work on Windows 7
Alas I do not have the permissions to play with hosts file and explore further

If the PC does not have IPv6 installed then creating an IPv6 Binding should raise an exception at runtime. So I suspect IPv6 is actually installed (does TIdStack.SupportsIPv6 return True?) but is just not being used on his adapters. In any case, even if you create an IPv6 Binding, if the client uses IPv4 to connect to the server then the IPv6 Binding simply won't be touched. Each Binding runs independent of each other.  So that can't be the source of your speedup.

Also, note that if you don't specify any Bindings then the server will just create its own internally, and it will try to create both IPv4 and IPv6 Bindings if possible.  So, if you just create 1 IPv4 Binding yourself, that will simply disable the server's use of IPv6.

GStack.SupportsIPv6 and GStack.SupportsIPv4 are both TRUE. I cannot see how that explains anything :(

But sure enough, if I coment out the IPv6 Bindings.Add it all goes slow again. So it looks like IPv4 is (mis-)configured to be slow somehow. will try to pester the Admin to get to the bottom of this. I imagine IPv6 is only fast because it was left alone :) Come to think of it - IdHttp was fast regardless: so would it use IPv6 over IPv4 ?

TIdHTTP uses IPv6 only if the URL host/IP is in brackets, eg: http://[HostOrIP]/

As per edit of the answer - it seems TIdHttp works better precisely because it does not automatically attempt to go via IPv6 ?

"WinHttp trying IPv6, failing and then switching to IPv4 is what causes slowdown when server Bindings do not include IPv6" - makes sense, assuming WinHttp does not simply attempt both IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time in parallel and use whichever one succeeds first.
